# Vertical space, equivalent of \makebox, in a table cell in LaTeX?

Tags: tabularray

Is there a package which can distribute words vertically in a table cell in LaTeX?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray,tabularx}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{talltblr}[
    caption={table}
    ]{colspec={X[c] X[c]}
    }
\SetCell[r=2]{m}{{{H e l l o}}}&{{{1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7}}}\\
&{{{8\\9}}}
\end{talltblr}
\begin{talltblr}[
    caption={table}
    ]{colspec={X[c] X[c]}
    }
\SetCell[r=2]{m}{{{H\\e\\l\\l\\o}}}&{{{1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7}}}\\
&{{{8\\9}}}
\end{talltblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the second table, `Hello` is not distributed vertically. So how to make it vertically distributed in that cell?

Comment: I think you have to learn some plain TeX and do this one manually, measure the natural vertical height of the 2 cells in the second column, create a new box and insert a `vfil` between each row (or set baselineskip to 1fil)

Comment: Hello. How to measure the natural vertical height of the cell?@user202729

Comment: well if you want to center relative to the 1-7, then why do you merge also with the row containing the 8 and 9?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for your reply. You are right. I just want to make a case which was not considered thoroughly. Is there a package like `\makebox` to vertically distribute words?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I answer the question. With tikzpicture...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{}
\SetCell[r=2]{m}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center),inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,node distance=1ex]
  \node (A) {H};
  \node (B) [below=of A] {e};
  \node (C) [below=of B] {l};
  \node (D) [below=of C] {l};
  \node (E) [below=of D] {o};
\end{tikzpicture}}
&{1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7}\\
&{8\\9}
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

UPDATE after the comment, I'm not an expert with expl3.

- evaluation of the tikz box with distance 0pt
- evaluation of the tblr box with distance 0pt
- calcul of the distance and modification in the tikz box

  ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{tabularray}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary {positioning}
   \begin{document}
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   \ExplSyntaxOn
   \dim_new:N \distance
   \dim_set:Nn \distance {0pt}
   \ExplSyntaxOff
   \newcommand{\mytikz}{%
   \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center),inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,node distance=\distance]
   \node (A) {H};
   \node (B) [below=of A] {e};
   \node (C) [below=of B] {l};
   \node (D) [below=of C] {l};
   \node (E) [below=of D] {o};
   \end{tikzpicture}}
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   \newcommand{\mytblr}{
   %\begin{tblr}[b]{hlines}%
   \begin{tblr}[b]{}
   \SetCell[r=2]{m}{%
   \mytikz
   }
   &{1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7}\\
   &{8\\9}
   \end{tblr}}
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   \ExplSyntaxOn

   \vbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { \mytblr }
   \vbox_set:Nn \l_tmpb_box { \mytikz }

   The~ height~ of~
   \verb|\l_tmpa_box|~ is:~ \dim_use:N \box_ht_plus_dp:N \l_tmpa_box
   \par
   The~ height~ of~
   \verb|\l_tmpb_box|~ is:~ \dim_use:N \box_ht_plus_dp:N \l_tmpb_box
   \par


   \dim_set:Nn \distance {
   \fp_to_decimal:n {(\dim_use:N \box_ht_plus_dp:N \l_tmpa_box-\dim_use:N \box_ht_plus_dp:N \l_tmpb_box)/5}pt}

   % \rule{4pt}{\dim_use:N \box_ht_plus_dp:N \l_tmpa_box} \vspace{-\dim_use:N \box_ht_plus_dp:N \l_tmpa_box}\mytblr
   \ExplSyntaxOff

   \mytblr
   \end{document}
  ```

[image]

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your reply. But the `Hello` was not distributed as high as `123456789`.

Comment: With   \begin{tblr}{rowsep=0pt} ?

Comment: The space among `H`, `e`, `l`, `l` and `o` is small so the first column and the second column seem not suited.

Comment: with node distance=4ex ?

Comment: Maybe it can. But is there a way to automatically vertically distribute those?

Comment: A new version, I think we can do better

Comment: Okay. It is a useful way but to difficult for me when I meet a situation like this one. Thanks a lot.